# How to detect screen rotation in android

Tags: android, rotation, oncreate

How to detect screen rotation in android  in other words how to catch screen rotation event in android  ? does `onCreate` be called in every rotation ?

Answer (score 1):

Activity has a method `onConfigurationChanged()` that is a call back for screen rotation when the activity is running. See the documentation for more details:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onConfigurationChanged(android.content.res.Configuration)